# Unable to get list sensor list in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

i have problem getting list of available sensors on emulator

my code:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> sensList = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
Sensor s1 = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

i get empty list at both the places.

i verified that emulator has sensors by checking emulator logs:

also.
connecting to emulator(using telnet) and using sensor status, i get the following output.

```
acceleration: enabled.
magnetic-field: enabled.
orientation: enabled.
temperature: enabled.
proximity: enabled.
```

permissions in manifest are:

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AndroidSensorList extends ListActivity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       SensorManager sensorManager
        = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
       List<Sensor> listSensor
        = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

       List<String> listSensorType = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(int i=0; i<listSensor.size(); i++){
        listSensorType.add(listSensor.get(i).getName());
       }

       setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
               listSensorType));
       getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   }
}
```

Also in your Emulator you have to add Hardware property by editing your avd and click on new under Hardware Property, you can add:

Accelerometer, Magnetic Fields support, Orientation Support, Temperature ... don't forget to set values to true

Comment: i followed the same steps but i get empty list returned. i am using sdk version 2.3.3

Comment: @MacHiry click on AVD icon and pick the emulator that you use and click edit and tell me what you see in Hardware Property

Comment: i checked that, sensors are enabled